# Split a long sub-expression in an f-string into multiple lines

Tags: python, coding-style, f-string

I have a Python f-string containing one really long expression:

```py
my_string = f"some text {this + is + a + really + long + expression + because + it + contains + some + really + long + identifiers} some more text"
```

Is there a way to split this f-string into multiple lines, say because I want to stick to a given maximum line length? Using backslash to split the sub-expression is not legal, nor are any tricks using parentheses:

```py
illegal = f"some text {this + is + a + really + long + \
                       expression + because + it + contains + \
                       some + really + long + identifiers} some more text"
#SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash

also_illegal = f"some text {(this + is + a + really + long + 
                             expression + because + it + contains + 
                             some + really + long + identifiers)} some more text"
#SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line XXX)

more_illegal = (f"some text {this + is + a + really + long + 
                             expression + because + it + contains + 
                             some + really + long + identifiers} some more text")
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line ZZZ)
```

I do **not** want to introduce a new variable to store the value. I know that this would allow me to split the expression any way I want. But I do not want to change what the code does just for style points.

Comment: What do you mean, "not legal"? It doesn't work for you, or you don't want it?

Comment: It is not legal Python syntax. Splitting a strings that way will raise SyntaxErrors. At least the examples that I showed. Unless there is some variation that I missed, that is legal.

Comment: Just to clarify: I want an answer regarding Python syntax or its limits. I know perfectly well how to change the code so that the issue does not arise. But it feels wrong to functionally change code as the answer to a question regarding formatting. Therefore I was wondering if it is just impossible to split an f-string like this or if there is some other way that I do not know about.

Comment: Aren't the error messages enough? Here more on [string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) and about [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) and [PEP 498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#specification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with f-strings, per se, but with non-triple-quoted strings.

```
>>> f"""some text { 3 +
... 5}"""
'some text 8'
```

Comment: But it is a problem of f-string when you have instead ```f"""{this1 + that2 + ... = }"""``` or more often ```f"""{(this1, that2, ...) = }"""```, as it introduces the newline into the output.